# Challenges, Advantages if we migrate from SSL to TLS 1.2 in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl, tls1.2

We are hosting our application in tomcat 6. Now SSL has been used and we need to migrate it to TLS 1.2. As am new to these things, Request your help for below queries.
1. Whats the advantages if we migrate it to TLS 1.2?
2. What are the challenges?
3. What changes needs to be done at server level and the network level?

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly broad question, but I'll try to answer quickly.

> 1. What are the advantages if we migrate to TLSv1.2

You may have regulatory requirements to move to TLSv1.2. (e.g. PCI-DSS, HIPAA/HITECH, etc.), but there is a better reason: security is improved overall if you support the higher-version protocols. It would be best to *completely disable* SSLv3 and only use TLSv1 and later. If you have a community of users who are generally pretty up-to-date with their software, then you can likely move to TLSv1.2 and not even bother with the lower protocols. You can definitely support all of TLSv1, TLSv1.1, and TLSv1.2 all with a single configuration.

Later versions of the spec allow the use of better cipher suites, including those with ephemeral key agreement (EDHE) as well as more efficient elliptic-curve (EC) algorithms to be used. These cipher suites offer better privacy and security (e.g. forward-security) as well as better performance (EC is faster for the same "level" of encryption versus e.g. RSA).

> 2. What are the challenges?

In order to support TLSv1.2, you may have to upgrade your JRE to Java 1.7 or later. I would argue that you should be on Java 1.8 at this point, regardless.

Tomcat will use whatever algorithms and protocols are supported by the JRE, but the default configuration (e.g. for Tomcat 6) may require you to change your configuration a bit to enable the better protocols and disable the older, less-secure ones.

> 3a. What changes need to be done at the server level?

Basically, you need to disable SSLv3 and enable everything up through TLSv1.2. In practice, that means that your `<Connector>` configuration should look like this:

```
<Connector sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" [...]
```

> 3b. What changes need to be done at the network level?

None at all.